# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline using local-only Docker Image

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I utilize a local image in my agent.docker definition.

I am aware of the syntax for using images from Docker Hub.

How would I utilize an image that is available locally e.g. An image I can see when running `docker images`

Documentation Snippet

```
docker

Execute the Pipeline, or stage, with the given container which will be dynamically provisioned on a node pre-configured to accept Docker-based Pipelines, or on a node matching the optionally defined label parameter. docker also optionally accepts an args parameter which may contain arguments to pass directly to a docker run invocation. For example: agent { docker 'maven:3-alpine' } or

agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3-alpine'
        label 'my-defined-label'
        args  '-v /tmp:/tmp'
    }
}
```

Comment: When you can guarantee that the image is available locally, just specify the image name. Then the docker daemon shouldn't try to download it from Docker Hub.

Comment: That does not work with the latest version of the pipeline.